# Как узнать какой сейчас день недели в Java?

Tags: java

Надо чтобы функция выводила `string`, чтобы можно было поставить в `label`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
System.out.println (new SimpleDateFormat ( "EEEE" ).format ( new Date() )) ;
```

**update** : нет смысла конструктору `Date` передавать `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

javadoc конструктора без параметров:

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.

исходный код конструктора `java.util.Date` :

```
public Date() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Comment: Eclipse перевертела мне эту функцию в это:
 String day = new SimpleDateFormat ("EEEE").format (new Date(0));
И вследствии того, он мне выводит что сегодня четверг :c

Comment: так а че ты 0 передаешь в new Date(0)?? передай туда System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: @Дмитрий Алексеевич а зачем вы передаете 0 в конструктор дейт обьекта? в примере я вообще ничего не передаю (т.е. получаем обьект дейт который указывает на текущий момент времени и даты)

Comment: вот именно, что я 0 не передавал впринципе, меня IDE заставила это сделать, иначе бы она не закомпилилась :(

Comment: @jmu, ну почему же так категорично? конечно это лишнее, но для наглядности и очевидно можно добавлять, что бы не было путаницы...

Comment: 2 @Gorets:

* я не говорил что так делать нельзя, я говорил что так делать бессмысленно 
* от добавления данного параметра код понятнее не становится
* надо приучать себя читать javadoc (я имею в виду не вас)